# Can I restore a single app backup without impacting other apps?

Tags: adb, backup, restore

This may be a stupid question in the sense that it is obvious to everyone who has done it once - but I haven't.

So, I know that `adb backup -f myAndroidBackup.ab com.corp.app` can back up a single app's data without root. Will restoring this backup with `adb` touch only `com.corp.app`, or will it wipe other apps first?